# Tor browser will not open - tried everything I know

Tags: windows, tor-browser-bundle, troubleshooting, performance

My Tor browser just randomly stopped launching. I'm running Windows 10. I have tried to delete everything tor related and re-download multiple times, messed with the firewall settings, etc. The information I have been able to find is either not recent, not for Win 10, or is too advanced for me to understand. I cannot even find anything in the TBB that I can try and manipulate to try and fix the problem.

Whenever I click the browser to open it, the little blue circle on the mouse pointer (I'm not sure what the technical name is LOL) starts spinning as if something is being executed, but then it just stops and nothing happens.

I just don't understand how it could go from working fine, then to not at all within a couple hours. The computer wasn't even being used.

Please help!! Thank you!

Comment: One idea would be to try to run it from the `cmd` prompt, if you know how to do that. (Basically open `cmd`, navigate to the relevant directory, and run `start-tor-browser`, or whatever the `.exe` is on Windows.) That should hopefully output some useful logs...

Comment: Also checking the windows application logs and any antivirus logs.

Comment: I had the exact same problem and was ready to pay someone $500 to fix it until I read somewhere on this site (can't remember the exact thread - I read about a million of them while trying to 'fix' this) - Temporarily disable whatever anti virus program(s) you may be running - once TOR has made it's initial connection, you can re-enable your AV programs.It took me two days of frustration for this 2 minute fix. [sigh]

Comment: had the same problem- Tried everything that has been posted over numerous sites which never worked for me. Finally came across an easy fix that is worth trying: go to start tor browser icon- right click.
click properties, click compatibility- at the bottom there is a box for "run this program as administrator". my box was not checked. I clicked on the box and applied it. Boom- problem solved :) Opens right away now. Hope this works for others.

Comment: I had a browser pluggin called IBM Trusteer Protection. I had to disable this to alow Tor Browser to work. Tor used to work fine but suddenly Trusteer started blocking it.

Comment: I tried all the above suggestion, one of them worked for me, I shutdown IBM Trustee Protection on my Windows 10 and Tor started immediately.
In search window type trustee protection. It lists several options, one of them is 'stop trustee'. choose this option and follow instructions.

Comment: I have the same problem on a Windows 10 PC. I have no `IBM Trusteer Protection` software installed, nor `WebRoot`. There is no error log anywhere. Web search returns nothing helpful.

Comment: @DJMiller - Your suggestion of accessing the Tor properties and checking the "Run as Administrator" box on the Compatibility tab worked brilliantly for me. I've been unable to launch Tor successfully for many weeks now and making that one change solved the problem. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Tor not opening while Webroot was running, after May 1, 2016, when it did open earlier. I checked the Event Viewer and saw the faulting application path was to firefox.exe in the Tor browser folder. So, I went to Identity Protection in Webroot and looked in Application Protection to find that firefox.exe entry. There were several firefox.exe entries but only one that was in the Tor browser folder. On that one, I changed the setting from "Protect" to "Allow." And that worked to allow me to open Tor.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same exact issue, and unfortunately all I can do at this point is provide more info. This crash just started recently. Downloading the latest distribution and re-installing does not resolve it. The entry in the Windows application log looks like this:

```
Faulting application name: firefox.exe, version: 38.8.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Faulting module name: msvcrt.dll, version: 7.0.10586.0, time stamp: 0x5632d722
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0008a209
Faulting process id: 0x1c4c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1ad8b983b48b3
Faulting application path: C:\Portables\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll
Report Id: f45757fc-aa03-48f6-894f-d01d8f034248
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Crash report:

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=131076694244616531
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=131076694245866747
ReportIdentifier=546b6bc4-1982-11e6-bf49-60a44c60dc89
IntegratorReportIdentifier=f672dc98-8995-4d1f-a5cb-07426b7cd345
WOW64=1
NsAppName=firefox.exe
Response.BucketId=3f729cc32219c25b9a23ec4d80593ab3
Response.BucketTable=1
Response.LegacyBucketId=108151515479
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=firefox.exe
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=38.8.0.0
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=00000000
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[3].Value=msvcrt.dll
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=7.0.10586.0
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=5632d722
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=c0000005
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[7].Value=0008a209
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.10586.2.0.0.256.48
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=bdcb
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=bdcb33e65a9843796b7ec31cc25bda3b
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=b1e9
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=b1e9e5e7403b4fc1f3fdca02e40d62b6
UI[2]=C:\Portables\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe
UI[3]=Tor Browser has stopped working
UI[4]=Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.
UI[5]=Check online for a solution and close the program
UI[6]=Check online for a solution later and close the program
UI[7]=Close the program
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Portables\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WRusr.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Portables\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\msvcr100.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\windows.storage.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\shlwapi.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\PSAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[22]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\shcore.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\powrprof.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\urlmon.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WININET.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OLEACC.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSIMG32.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Secur32.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\iertutil.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[35]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Portables\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\mozsqlite3.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Portables\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\mozalloc.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Portables\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\mozglue.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Portables\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\nspr4.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Portables\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\libssp-0.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.DLL
LoadedModule[45]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Portables\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\plds4.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Portables\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\plc4.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Portables\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\nssutil3.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Portables\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\nss3.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Portables\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\smime3.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Portables\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\ssl3.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Portables\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\xul.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\COMDLG32.DLL
LoadedModule[54]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\FirewallAPI.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NETAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.10586.0_none_d3c2e4e965da4528\COMCTL32.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SETUPAPI.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[59]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\RASAPI32.DLL
LoadedModule[60]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINTRUST.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\RASDLG.DLL
LoadedModule[62]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[63]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[64]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
LoadedModule[65]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USP10.dll
LoadedModule[66]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\UxTheme.dll
LoadedModule[67]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINSPOOL.DRV
LoadedModule[68]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.DLL
LoadedModule[69]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[70]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MPRAPI.dll
LoadedModule[71]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\rtutils.dll
LoadedModule[72]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\rasman.dll
LoadedModule[73]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DPAPI.dll
LoadedModule[74]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DAVHLPR.DLL
LoadedModule[75]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NETUTILS.DLL
LoadedModule[76]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SAMCLI.DLL
LoadedModule[77]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\fwbase.dll
LoadedModule[78]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
LoadedModule[79]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dwrite.dll
LoadedModule[80]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\clbcatq.dll
LoadedModule[81]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\propsys.dll
LoadedModule[82]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINNSI.DLL
LoadedModule[83]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[84]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Dnsapi.dll
LoadedModule[85]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[86]=C:\Portables\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\browser\components\browsercomps.dll
LoadedModule[87]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[88]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\napinsp.dll
LoadedModule[89]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
LoadedModule[90]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\NLAapi.dll
LoadedModule[91]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
LoadedModule[92]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll
LoadedModule[93]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
LoadedModule[94]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\efswrt.dll
LoadedModule[95]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll
LoadedModule[96]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\edputil.dll
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=Tor Browser
AppPath=C:\Portables\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=FA6E326183824350C9D56FBCD3354E3D
```

### Update

I removed TBB from my machine and installed the WindowsSDK so I could try some debugging. After reinstalled, I now get a Firefox dialog on startup saying "Couldn't load XPCOM". I did some digging and the answer to this question worked for me:

[Error message "Cannot load XPCOM" at the start of Tor Browser](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/error-message-cannot-load-xpcom-at-the-start-of-tor-browser)

After manually allowing all the files that Webroot had picked up from my Tor installation, the browser launched fine. I'm guessing a recent Webroot update has some definitions in it that block some vital Tor components. I noticed Webroot's web protection is also flagging torproject.org as high risk.

Your case may be different, but start by checking your antivirus.