# Tor Browser Will Not Start

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

(Windows 10 Home, 64-Bit Operating System, x64-based processor)

Tor Browser will not start. When clicking the "Start Tor Browser" icon all I get is the "Tor unexpectedly exited" message. Pressing the "Restart Tor" button I get the "Waiting for Tor to start..." message, and then it goes back to the "Tor unexpectedly exited" message again. It will Not Restart and there is no Tor Log to copy to Clipboard.

Tor was working fine and then one day I tried using it and all I got was the "Tor unexpectedly exited" message. I uninstalled it and tried re-installing the latest version but I still keep getting the same "Tor unexpectedly exited" message with No Tor Log.

Uninstall and re-install did Not work.
Run as Admin did Not work.
Disabling Internet Security software did Not work.
Compatibility Modes did Not work.

Searched similar problems and could not find a fix for my problem.

Note: Tor Browser works fine on 2 other computers running same Internet Security on Same Network. One is Win 7 and other is still running Vista. It only stopped working on the Win 10 computer.

Is there a simple fix for this problem?

[image: Screen Shot of Message when trying to run Tor Browser]

^ This is all I get when trying to run Tor ^

Comment: I have got the exact same issue and I am on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 .. It was working perfectly fine and then suddenly I got this window popping up ?? Please can someone help ? That's now 2 of us encountering the problem. Helpdesk please can you read this ? ... Regards.

Comment: Downloaded and installed Tor 7.5a1 with no luck. I still have the same problem. All I get is same "Tor unexpectedly exited" message. There is no "Tor Log" available to post.

Comment: Any luck on your end solving this issue? I am still having the same problem even with the latest version of Tor (7.5a1).  The problem is only on one of my computers. I have 2 others that it is working fine on. If you find a solution, please post it here. Thank You!

Comment: I have had the same issue with the TOR browser failing to start in windows 10. After much searching and faffing about I came across the answer from Digitaldogbag above. I disabled IBM Trusteer Rapport and hey presto the TOR browser started without issue. Sincere thanks to Digitaldogbag.
I just wish that such conflicts could be flagged up by the OS at the outset as it would save a huge amount of time and brain damage for all concerned

Comment: I have the same problem on a Windows 10 PC. I have no `IBM Trusteer Protection` software installed, nor `WebRoot` (see relevant question here: https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/10433/31106). There is no error log anywhere. Web search returns nothing helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Trusteer Rapport Endpoint protection is related to banking online info at 
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=what+is+trusteer+rapport+endpoint+protection&t=ffnt&ia=web
I recently had an update to this about the same time TOR updated to version 7
and experienced the lack of connection.

To cure this find Trusteer Endpoint in all programs click on the file and you will see start/stop and console click on stop copy the code into the box enter
and then it will work.

You should start this again before banking as it is an extra layer of protection

Regards hope this works for you all

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this comment, so it is of no help without a more detailed description of what you are saying.

Comment: Had the same problem. After reading your post I checked my programs for Trusteer and saw that it was updated the same day I was unable to get into TOR. Followed your instructions and it now works fine now. Thank you.