# Error message "libxul.so: undefined symbol: gdk_window_get_visual Cannot load XPCOM” at the start of Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux, error

My machine is Linux and I try the latest TBB (6.0.4). But when I run TBB I get the error message (strangely TBB 5.5 works perfectly fine)

```
$./start-tor-browser.desktop --verbose
Launching './Browser/start-tor-browser --detach --verbose'...
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file <...>/Browser/libxul.so:
<...>/Browser/libxul.so: undefined symbol: gdk_window_get_visual
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

I saw [the solution](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/error-message-cannot-load-xpcom-at-the-start-of-tor-browser) for this question but it is Windows specific.

How to solve this on Linux?

Comment: I am getting the same error. I run Mepis 11, 32 bit.

Comment: Do you have `gdk-pixbuf` installed? It's trying to fulfill a symbol requirement and it cannot, it suggests this library may be missing.

Comment: that library is installed and is in the package `librsvg2-common`.